# How to get hold of a value from modal popup angular js

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a input box in modal popup , i want that value in my main controller which invoked the modal.

Comment: Are you using the `modal` directive from `ui-bootstrap` or another modal provider?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:

```
//Modal controller
$rootScope.$broadcast('modal:nameOfModal:onSave', { data: data })

//Any other controller
$scope.$on('modal:nameOfModal:onSave', function(event, data) { ... } )
```

Right way:

- [Modal creator](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
- `Factory` with methods representing each modal type you need
- Each method method of `Factory` (like `Factory.confirmationWindow()`) returning a `promise` that should be handled separately in controllers that rise appropriate modal
- Call something like in your controller

  ```
  Controller.propotype.openModal = function() {
      ModalsFactory.confirmationModal().then(function(result) {
          //using result inside of your controller
          //if clicked ok
      }).catch(function() {
          //behavior to be called when modal canceled 
      });
  }
  ```

Pros:

1. Totally separates logic
2. Allow to define different behavior of same modals in different controllers

Cons:

1. `ModalsFactory` will be big file